# What is the default build process used by IntelliJ for Java projects?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ant

Building Java projects straight from the IDE in IntelliJ has been nice. It's fast and it just works. I wasn't able to find any documentation on how IntelliJ does these default builds. I'm guessing it uses Ant? What I want to do is **automate this fast and painless build process for anyone who downloads my project**. Is that possible?

I've usually used Maven, but it's very slow and error prone. I actually wasn't even able to convert this to a Maven project, because Maven refuses to find JUnit despite setting up the dependency according to examples in the official docs. I also tried to generate Ant build files from the IDE, but those do not work out of the box and after googling a bit, seems like that is not a good approach?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? *Maven refuses to find JUnit*? You don't need Ant... Maybe you can show your setup?

Comment: My question is what is the default build process used by IntelliJ for Java projects - and how can I automate this fast and painless build process for anyone who downloads my project? Sorry if the Maven talk was distracting. That was mainly to explain why I want to use IntelliJ's build process intead of Maven (which I was expecting people to recommend).

Comment: But if you have a Maven project, IntelliJ invokes Maven.....

Comment: As far as I know does Intellij not use a specific Build System by default. It directly invokes the java compiler

Comment: @Tunaki It was not a Maven project until 1 hour ago. It was just a regular Java project with no Maven.

Comment: So you want magic that compiles your project automatically just like that when checking it out? Then Maven is the tool for that. Still not sure what the actual problem is with JUnit and all.

Comment: I don't really understand what all the hate is for. Is it because I wanted to use build tool X instead of build tool Y? The question is clear and the answer wasn't available on public documentation or Google. Why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has its own build system, called JPS. It has limited support for automatic download of dependencies and it's really hard to invoke from the command line, so it's unlikely to be the best option for everyone who downloads your project, unless you want to force them to use IntelliJ IDEA.