# What magic happens when IntelliJ compiles my Kotlin project?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, build, ant

I currently know that `kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar` compiles my hello world program written in kotlin. Furthermore I am able to execute my program via `java -jar hello.jar`.

Setting up a Kotlin "Hello world!" console application example in IntelliJ I may choose between different Build Systems (Maven, Gradle, IntelliJ).

I would like to know what happens in the background using the IntelliJ Build System for example?
It seems that there is an ant script running considering the Build Output:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks…
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Kotlin: connecting to daemon
Kotlin: compiling [firstKotlinApp]
Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.6.10-release-923 (JRE 17.0.1+12-39)
Kotlin: performing incremental compilation analysis
Checking dependencies… [firstKotlinApp]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Updating dependency information… [firstKotlinApp]
Running 'after' tasks
Finished, saving caches…
Executing post-compile tasks…
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories…
04.01.22, 07:59 - Build completed successfully in 6 sec, 686 ms
```

Can someone help me out and direct me to the right place to look?

I already  tried to find information with several search engines.

Comment: The IntelliJ Build System seems to refer to [JPS](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/jps), according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856214/5133585). I can't find too much info about JPS itself, other than its source code though.

Comment: If you are also asking about Gradle or Maven, the commands that IntelliJ runs would be `gradle build` or `mvn package` or some variation of that.